# how to read multiple lines from stdin and store it in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to write a program that get's lines from the user (from STDIN) and store them in a linked list.

right now I'm getting only one line and terminate the program.
how can I change the code to keep getting lines from stdin?

also, if someone can tell me if I'm allocating and freeing memory as it should be it will be very helpful.

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int BUFF_SIZE = 128;

struct Node {
    char* data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* head = NULL;
struct Node* tail = NULL;

void free_list(struct Node* head)
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        free_list(head->next);
        free(head);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int curr_size = 0;

    char* pStr = malloc(BUFF_SIZE);
    curr_size = BUFF_SIZE;

    printf("%s", "please print multiple lines\n");
    if (pStr != NULL)
    {
        char c;
        int i = 0;

        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        {
            pStr[i++] = c;

            if (i == curr_size)
            {
                curr_size = i + BUFF_SIZE;
                pStr = realloc(pStr, curr_size);
                if (pStr == NULL) return;
            }
        }
        pStr[i] = '\0';

        struct Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
        char* new_data = malloc(sizeof(pStr));
        new_data = pStr;
        new_node->data = new_data;

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = new_node;
            tail = new_node;
        }

        else
        {
            tail->next = new_node;
        }
    }

    free_list(head);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Few problems:

1. As of now you are terminating the reading upon reacieving the `\n`.

   ```
   if (pStr == NULL) return; //error

   int c;
   int i = 0;

   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
   {
      /*New word, insert into linked list*/
      if (c == '\n'){
          pStr[i] = '\0';

          struct Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
          char* new_data = malloc(i+1);
          strcpy(new_data, pStr);
          new_node->data = new_data;

          if (head == NULL)
          {
               head = new_node;
               tail = new_node;
          }
          else
          {
               tail->next = new_node;
               tail = new_node;
          }
          i = 0; //Reset the index
      }
      else {

          pStr[i++] = c;
          if (i == curr_size)
          {
              curr_size = i + BUFF_SIZE;
              pStr = realloc(pStr, curr_size);
              if (pStr == NULL) return;
          }
      }
   }
   ```
2. Memory leaks and node `data` will be always pointing to latest content of `pStr`.

   ```
   char* new_data = malloc(sizeof(pStr)); 
   new_data = pStr;   //Memory leak here
   new_node->data = new_data;
   ```

   change it to

   ```
   char* new_data = malloc(i+1);
   strcpy(new_data, pStr);
   new_node->data = new_data;
   ```

   > sizeof(pStr) is size of pointer not the string length.
3. You need to update `tail` after each node is inserted to list.

   ```
    else
    {
        tail->next = new_node;
    }
   ```

   to

   ```
    else
   {
       tail->next = new_node;
       tail = new_node;
    }
   ```

Comment: wow thanks! thats helps a lot. after changing what you said I've tried to insert a few lines and print the head and tail at the end - and they have the same data . do you have an idea why its happening?

Comment: sorry I'm new here, how can I do it?

Comment: @beginnerCoder under the upvote counter next to the answer is a checkmark. click it. It should turn green. And fyi, there is still a problem with this code. `c` should be `int`, not `char`.

Comment: @beginnerCoder You should also go back to your old questions and accept the one of useful answers, this is how you show gratitude towards one who helped you :)

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanlks, why it should be int?

Comment: @beginnerCoder Because that's what [`getchar()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns, and it's important, especially when comparing against `EOF` (which you're doing).

Comment: `struct Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));` (copied from the original source) is wrong. Must be `sizeof(struct Node)` or `sizeof *new_node`

Comment: The line `char* new_data = malloc(i+1);` should be followed with: `if(new_data) {...` to verify `malloc` was successful before using it.